# jinja2: replace a variable based on the value of a previous variable

Tags: python, jinja2

I am using jinja2 to dynamically create a latex document. I am new to jinja2 and its syntax. I am using this jinja env in a python file:

```
latex_jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    block_start_string = '((*',
    block_end_string = '*))',
    variable_start_string = '(((',
    variable_end_string = ')))',
    comment_start_string = '((=',
    comment_end_string = '=))',
    loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.abspath('.'))
)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    template = latex_jinja_env.get_template('template.tex') # pass in the template file
    render_template = template.render(blocks = blocks, **options) # pass in all jinja vars as a big dictionary
    print render_template
```

In the template.tex file I have this situation:

```
((( var1 ))) ( ((( var2 ))) ) other text...
```

`var1` can get replaced by a string that can be either `big` or `small`, `var2` with an integer. I would like that `var2` gets replaced only when `var1` gets the value `small`. How can translate that into jinja2? thanks

Comment: Why not use an `if` statement?

Comment: @DanielRoseman That is what I would use in python, how to write that in template.tex file using  jija2 syntax?

Comment: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#if

Comment: @syntonym Thanks, that is it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple if statement (with the syntax defined in the latex_jinja_env var ) does the job:

```
((( var1 ))) 
((* if block13_var1 == "small" *)) 
( ((( var2 ))) )
((* endif *))
```